# Sum all amounts paid by specific student

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name titled:

```
Fee_payment
payment_id  student_id  name    class_id  term         year     amount creation_timestamp
         1           7  john    JHS2A     second_term  20014    34     1416610800
         2           5  Grace   JHS2B     second_term  20014    34     1416610856
         3           6  john    JHS2A     second_term  20014    56     1416610800
```

I want to sum total amount paid by john if user clicks on fee records. I am able to fetch only the current amount paid but not able to sum all amounts paid by a student.

What I am looking for is if for example john appears twice, I should be able to sum payments made by john together based on term and creation_timestamp.

What I have tried:

```
 <div class="box-content">
        <?php foreach($edit_data as $row):?>


        <div class="pull-left">

            <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:100;">

            <?php echo get_phrase('payment_to');?>
            <img width="50" height="30" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/logo.png" style="max-height:100px;margin:20px 0px;" />
            </span>
            <br />
            <?php echo $system_name;?>
            <br />
            <?php echo $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type'=>'address'))->row()->description;?>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:100;">
                <?php echo get_phrase('credited_account:');?>
            </span>
            <br />
                <?php echo $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->row()->name;?>
            <br />
                <?php echo get_phrase('student_id');?> : 
                <?php echo "FAVECSID0000", $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->row()->student_id;?>
            <br />
                <?php echo get_phrase('class');?> : 
                <?php 
                $class_id   =   $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->row()->class_id;
                echo $this->db->get_where('class' , array('class_id'=>$class_id))->row()->name;
                ?>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <hr />
        <table width="100%" background="http://localhost/schoolmanager/uploads/backlogos.png">
            <tr style="background-color:#7087A3; color:#fff; padding:5px;">
                <td style="padding:5px;"><?php echo get_phrase('payment_details');?></td>
                <td width="30%" style="padding:5px;">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <?php echo get_phrase('amount');?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:100;">
                        <?php echo get_phrase('payment_made');?>
                    </span>
                    <br />

                </td>
                <td width="30%" style="padding:5px;">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:100;">
                        <?php echo "Gh", $row['amount'];?>  
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:100;">
                        <?php echo get_phrase('balance');?>
                    </span>
                    <br />
                    <?php echo $row['description'];?>
                    <?php 
                                $exams = $this->db->get_where('fee_payment', array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->result_array();
                                foreach($exams as $row):
                                ?>
                                <?php 

                                $ttpaid = sum($row['amount']);
                                echo $ttpaid;?>
                                 <?php
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                </td>
                <td width="30%" style="padding:5px;">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:100;">
                <?php 

                $tuition    =   $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->row()->tuition_fee;
                $status =   $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->row()->status_fee;
                $total_fees = $tuition + $status;
                $balance_fee = $total_fees - $row['amount'];
                echo "Gh", $balance_fee;
                ?>          
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td></td>
                <td width="30%" style="padding:5px;">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <hr />
                    <?php echo get_phrase('status');?> : <?php echo $row['status'];?>
                    <br />
                    <?php echo get_phrase('receipt_no:');?> : <?php echo "FAVECSFP0000",$row['payment_id'];?>
                    <br />
                    <?php echo get_phrase('date');?> : <?php echo date('m/d/Y', $row['creation_timestamp']);?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
<br />
<br />


        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:

```
Payment To
FAIRVIEW EDUCATIONAL CENTER
P O BOX 126
Credited Account:
john
Student Id : FAVECSID00007
Class : JHS2A
Payment Details     
Amount
Payment Made Gh34
Balance
```

Comment: Luckily, we seem to be talking about events some ways off into the future.

Comment: This looks like a ton of code not relevant to the question, and there's some missing information. What's `$this` (i.e. what framework are you working with? Codeigniter?). You can use SQL's `SUM` combined with a `WHERE` that selects the student, to let the database system do the sum.

Comment: In addition to `SUM(amount)`, use `group by student_id, term` and you it should be all rolled up.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about MySQL is that unlike a real sheet of paper, there is no reason to restrict yourself to a single table.  In this case you have your `Fee_payment` table but it seems like it might be best to add a second table such as `Students`.

In that case, you might have a table that looks like this:

```
Students
id   name            account_created
 1   John            1416610800
 2   Grace           1416609200
```

So in your `Fee_payment` table, you no longer have to store the name of the student.  You would simply use your `student_id` column to reference the `id` column in the `Students` table.  Then, when John is logged in (or someone looks up John based off of the rows that exist in the `Students` table), all you need to do is search the `Fee_payment` table for a `student_id` that matches John's.

In this case the query would be something like:

`SELECT sum(amount) FROM Fee_payment WHERE student_id = 1`

This would return the total amount paid by John, and give you exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: While it's good advice on design to split the table into two, it's strictly not a necessary step to do the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Simply execute SQL query to the sum  for specific name.

`select name,sum(amount) from table_name where name like 'john'`